# New line on the answers list starts too early

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, title, newline

A new line of the question title on the user's answers page starts too early (e.g. [Shog9's answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9?tab=answers&sort=newest&page=2)):

> [image: Shog9's answers]

It seems that the width of the blue margin (on the picture) should be slightly (?) reduced to prevent beginning a new line for the question's title, because there is a lot of space to fit the ending of the title that is currently placed on the new line.